# Getting mysql row that doesn't conflict with another row

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that link together through an id one is "submit_moderate" and one is "submit_post"

The "submit_moderate" table looks like this

```
id     moderated_by     post
1      James            60
2      Alice            32
3      Tim              18
4      Michael          60
```

Im using a simple query to get data from the "submit_post" table according to the "submit_moderate" table.

```
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submit_moderate WHERE moderated_by!='$user'");
```

`$user` is the person who is signed in.

Now my problem is when I run this query, with the user 'Michael' it will retrieve this

```
1   James   60
2   Alice   32
3   Tim     18
```

Now technically this is correct however I don't want to retrieve the first row because 60 is associated with Michael as well as James. Basically I don't want to retrieve that value '60'.

I know why this is happening however I can't figure out how to do this. I appreciate any hints or advice I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT post
  FROM submit_moderate
 WHERE post NOT IN (SELECT post
                      FROM submit_moderate
                     WHERE moderated_by = 'Michael')
```

PS: not sure, but in some cases it probably would worth changing select-part of the nested query to `SELECT DISTINCT post`

Comment: Ditto. But I had a slightly worse solution, so thanks, I learnt something today.

Comment: Yeah this works but what happens if the user is tim then won't James and Michael both come up? The point is I'm trying to allow users to moderate posts however the same post could technically be pulled twice.

Comment: @user939951: I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: Essentially if the user 'Tim' is logged in. He goes to moderate and the row associated with post 60 appears twice. Would I have to use distinct in order to only show it once?

Comment: @user939951: which columns do you need as a result? Only `post`?

Comment: Yes post because it will take the value found in post and associate it with another table called submit_post

Comment: I still get 60 twice with another user

Comment: @user939951: it's not possible with my query. If you use not exactly what I gave but with modification - you need to show it in your question, because I cannot base my further advices on guesses

Comment: What is it exactly you want me to show. I put exactly what you told me I didn't modify it.

Comment: @user939951: my query cannot return duplicate `post` values. For any user it returns only unique `post` values. Show your code with the query you use.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my mistake I didn't realize you updated it a second time. Thank you very much it works now!

Comment: @user939951: yep, probably I didn't make it clear that I updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $user = 'Michael';

If u really don't want the 1st row of user as you said that james matches with the michael in posts
then go for

$post = mysql_query_first("SELECT post FROM submit_moderate WHERE moderated_by='$user'");

$get_posts =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submit_moderate WHERE moderated_by!='$user' and post!='$post');

or

$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submit_moderate WHERE post NOT IN (SELECT post FROM submit_moderate WHERE moderated_by = 'Michael') and moderated_by != 'Michael' ");

Comment: you can use the above nested query also

Comment: SELECT *  FROM submit_moderate  WHERE post NOT IN (SELECT post
                      FROM submit_moderate
                     WHERE moderated_by = 'Michael') and moderated_by != 'Michael' ;